# Datatables() - pagination in PHP via AJAX in MySQLi

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

OK, I am at a loss with this one. I have searched all over, read the manual (which has a completely different syntax and only gives PDO examples) and in general spent way too much time on this just because I want to make it work in AJAX **because its the right thing to do**

So, I obviously have a datatable with lots of records and am struggling to get the pagination to work, search and ordering all work fine.

Following the manual, I can gather that the pagination is dealt with by using the `LIMIT` command on the SQL query, which then again gets the amount of rows from the `$_REQUEST` variable, modifying the query accordingly to show the correct `start, end` number of rows.

My problem now seems to be that datatables() indeed correctly calculates the number of rows that should be displayed (eg. 25 of 100), but then does not paginate, leaving me stuck on the 1st page with the same 25 entries.

This is supposed to be simple and comes out of the box when doing a classic POST submit, but when dealing with an AJAX call it all seems to get infinitely more difficult....

Appreciate any help with his as I am ready to give up.
Thanks

**Javascript:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">                    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#med_feedback').DataTable( {
            // load table data via AJAX
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{
                url: "../../plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php", // json datasource
                data: { action:"view_med_surveys", property: $("#property_select").val(), date: $("#daterangepicker").val() },
                type: "POST",   // connection method (default: GET)
            },
            "columns": [
                { "aaData": "Svy_ID" },
                { "aaData": "OSAT" },
                { "aaData": "INT" }    
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                {   // adjust survey output
                    targets: [0],
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        var Svy_ID = row[0];    // define Survey as a variable since array is an object

                        return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DetailSurveyModal" data-keyboard="true" data-id="' + Svy_ID +'">' + Svy_ID + '</a>';
                    },
                }
            ],
            select: {
              style: 'single',
              //items: 'cell'
            },
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            stateSave: true,
            buttons: [
              'copyHtml5',
              'excelHtml5',
              'csvHtml5',
              'pdfHtml5',
              {
                extend: 'print',
                message: 'DO NOT DISTRIBUTE'
              },
              {
              extend: 'collection',
              text: 'Others',
              buttons: [
                {
                  text: 'Toggle button',
                  action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                  dt.column( -4 ).visible( ! dt.column( -4 ).visible() );
                  }
                },
                'colvis',
                'columnsToggle',
              ]
              },
            ],
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "pageLength": 25,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": false,
            //"order": [[ 1, "asc" ], [ 3, "asc" ]],
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": true
        })
    });
  </script>
```

**Serverside PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action'] == 'view_med_surveys')) {

    if(isset($_SESSION['Access'])) {

        // Start MySQLi connection
        include 'connect_db.php';
        $db = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

        // display error if connection cannot be established
        if($db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']'); }

        // define variables
        $requestData = $_REQUEST;       // DataTables AJAX request  
        $property = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['property']);
        $med_date = str_replace(" - ","' AND '", mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['date']));

        // check if table exists
        $result = $db->query("SELECT `Survey ID` FROM `medallia_import_".$property."` WHERE WHERE DATE(`Survey Collected Date 1`) BETWEEN '".$med_date."' LIMIT 1");
        //if ($result->num_rows > 0) {      // if at least one record is found, proceed accordingly

            // show all records
            $sql = "SELECT `Survey ID`, `Overall Experience`, `Internet Service` FROM `medallia_import_".$property."` WHERE DATE(`Survey Collected Date 1`) BETWEEN '".$med_date."'";

            // run query to get total number of records
            $result = $db->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
            $totalData = $result->num_rows;

            // if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
            if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {
                $sql.=" AND ( `Survey ID` LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
                $sql.=" OR `Overall Experience` LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
                $sql.=" OR `Internet Service` LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
            }

            // sort by collection date - NO PAGINATION
            $sql.=" ORDER BY `Survey Collected Date 1` DESC LIMIT ".$requestData['start'].", ".$requestData['length']." ";
            //$sql.=" ORDER BY `Survey Collected Date 1` DESC";      // this works

            // run final query
            $result = $db->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));

            if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // return total number of rows for pagination
                $totalFiltered = $result->num_rows;

                // return table data - MUST BE NON-ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $data[] = array(
                        $row['Survey ID'],
                        $row['Overall Experience'],
                        $row['Internet Service']
                    );
                }

                // finalize array with elements required by DataTable plugin
                $json_data = array(
                  "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),  // unique draw number identifier (required)
                  "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),            // total number of records
                  "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ),        // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
                  "success"         => true,                            // success message - false / true (required)
                  "aaData"          => $data                            // table data as array
                );

                echo json_encode($json_data);
            } else {
              echo "No data found";
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The problem was that the query I used to count the totalFiltered variable already had the pagination limit in place, hence the `$result->num_rows` count would always be 25.

I circumvented this issue by splitting the final part of the SQL query into 2 bits ($sql 1 + $sql2), one query which has no limit element that I can use for the count, and another that has the limit which I can use for the DT result.

```
// if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {
    $sql.=" AND ( `Survey ID` LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR `Overall Experience` LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR `Internet Service` LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
}

// remove LIMIT for accurate DataTables row count
$sql2 = $sql . " ORDER BY `Medallia Collected Date 1` DESC";      // use for totalFiltered

// order Datatables result by date and apply pagination
$sql.=" ORDER BY `Medallia Collected Date 1` DESC LIMIT ".$requestData['start'].", ".$requestData['length'];

// run final query
$result = $db->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));

if($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // return total number of rows for pagination
    $result2 = $db->query($sql2) or die(mysqli_error($db));
    $totalFiltered = $result2->num_rows;

...

}
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

On your response array, shouldn't it be called "data" instead of "aaData" ? i can't find you setting the "dataSrc" property so that it uses "aaData" instead of "data".

Other than that check your **recordsTotal** and **recordsFiltered** values to see if all the queries are indeed working as expected.